# Prevent searching mail=* in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, acl, openldap, slapd

As an OpenLDAP admin, how can I prevent anonymous (non-authenticated) users from searching for e.g. mail=* with a single Asterisk?

```
ldapsearch ... "mail=*"
```

must be disabled, but

```
ldapsearch ... "mail=*test*"
```

must remain allowed.

I tried to add this rule but it did not help.

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to filter="(mail=*)"
  by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" read
  by * none
olcAccess: {1}to * 
  by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by * read
```

Comment: The `mail=*` specification selects *entries*, not *filters*. I doubt you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with OpenLDAP, but it's also not very useful to do, as it only takes a single `(mail=*@*)` to get around that restriction. (or if you forbid that, then `(mail=*@*.*)`, or some 26 or so `(mail=*a*)`, etc.)

Instead, set a size limit through `olcLimits` so that any anonymous query would only return e.g. 5 results at most – still possible to work around but much more annoying:

```
olcLimits: anonymous size.soft=5 size.hard=5
```